# How to parse JavaScript's DataObject from JSON with Android?

Tags: android, json, date, casting

I have this field in the JSON that I receive from the server:

```
/Date(1459461600000)/
```

How can I cast the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, how i cast in the string?

You don't, you *convert* it to a `Date` (or whatever form of date object you use in your app; a lot of people don't like `Date`) by extracting the number from that string and using it as milliseconds-since-the-Epoch (Jan 1st 1970 at midnight GMT).

`Date` has a constructor for that:

```
String str = "/Date(1459461600000)/";
long theNumber = Long.parseLong(str.substring(6, str.length() - 2));
Date dt = new Date(theNumber);
```

[Live example on ideone](http://ideone.com/ipJHex)

Whatever JSON library you're using may support using a *replacer* of some kind so you can do that during the parsing process rather than after-the-fact.